# Prevent execute-file from dump function name by using `strings` and `class-dump`

Tags: c++, c, reverting

I am writing a security app in c++. And when I run `strings app.name` I found there are many method name appear on the result.

Is there any way to hidden these method names? (I can change these function names manually, but I just wonder are there some flags can be added to compiler to hidden these names easily).

Comment: Make sure to strip debug symbols from your final executable. On Linux, use the `strip` command, or pass `-s` to GCC.

Comment: That, and compile without RTTI. Of course, that doesn't work if you use exception handling.

Comment: @SimonRichter: What will be the issue with RTTI? That will only offer names of classes, or is there any more information there?

Comment: As strings, only class names.

Answer (score 0):

Security through obscurity can still be overcome, but you could always `strip` your binary to remove all the debugging symbols and information.